# GitHub create repository with special root directory?

Tags: git, github

I want to make a GitHub repository. I want the root directory of it to be `C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\Folder\src`, and not `C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\Folder\src\RepoName`, but i cant manage to get this working. I tried creating a repository in "src", but that just created a folder with the repository name inside. I also want to avoid calling my repository "src".

Comment: Git repo names _are_ their containing directory.  This has nothing to do with GitHub.

Comment: @SLaks that is what I figured. But I am wondering if this can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command under `Folder` and it will create as you wish.

`git clone https://github.com/yourprojectname.git src`

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks!